# The value of the property is null or undefined, not a Function object

Tags: javascript, cewp

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I don't get the null or undefined error here, the input button is where I'm getting the error in F12 or firebug.......

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="MicrosoftAjax.js" runat="server" Defer="False" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SP.core.js" runat="server" Defer="False" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SP.js" runat="server" Defer="True" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:FormDigest ID="MyFormDigest" runat="server"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Scripting -->
<script>
function OnLoad()
    { 
   alert("Test");
    }   // End OnLoad
</script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div>
<input name="Test_JavaScript" type="button" value="Press Here Dummy!" onclick="JavaScript:OnLoad()"/> <!-- The value of the property 'OnLoad' is null or undefined, not a Function object, I don't get the error for this snippet -->
</div>
```

but I get it with this code. Can anyone shed some light on this error for this javascript noob, I've researched this error for over a day now....

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="MicrosoftAjax.js" runat="server" Defer="False" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SP.core.js" runat="server" Defer="False" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SP.js" runat="server" Defer="True" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:FormDigest ID="MyFormDigest" runat="server"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Scripting -->
<script>
function OnLoad()
{
        var siteUrl = '/sites/Test/subsite';
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");
    function retrieveListItems() {


    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('CAML Query');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Status' /></ViewFields>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));       
    }

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + '\nStatus: ' + oListItem.get_item('Status');
        }
    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
    }

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
 }  // End OnLoad
</script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div>
<input name="Test_JavaScript" type="button" value="Press Here Dummy!" onclick="JavaScript:OnLoad()"/>   <!-- The value of the property 'OnLoad' is null or undefined, not a Function object -->
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance I would say you get the error *"The value of the property is null or undefined, not a Function object"* because the function `OnLoad` is not defined. At least it should not be, based on your code, because your code has errors in it.

To fix the error try changing `camlQuery.set_viewXml('<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Status' /></ViewFields>');` into

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Status' /></ViewFields>");
```

Note ' vs " there.

Answer (score 1):

See eirik's answer. Here's the slightly modified code (structure).

```
function OnLoad() {
    var siteUrl = '/sites/Test/subsite';

    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");

    function retrieveListItems() {

        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('CAML Query');

        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.set_viewXml("<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Status' /></ViewFields>");
        collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.load(collListItem);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }
} //End OnLoad

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
   var listItemInfo = '';
   var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

   while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
       var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
       listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + '\nStatus: ' + oListItem.get_item('Status');
    }

    alert(listItemInfo);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```